# Maintain database and collection stats of all database and collections on MongoDB server - cron job

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cron

I want to run a CRON job that will retrieve stats for all databases and all the collection on the MongoDB production server. 
And then maintain this data somewhere, preferably in a database on the same server.

I am able to do it using Node.js, but is there any possibility to do it without having to set up Node.js on the server? Or what is the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/read/) part of mongodb doc to create a shell script that can retrieve, manipulate and save your data.
If you're using a Linux server you can run a cronjob and run your shell script using ***crontab*** (you can set a CRON job like this: `20 * * * * /path/to/script.sh`, don't forget fo make the script executable by `chmod +x /path/to/script.sh`).

Comment: Is there any downside of setting up node js running this with a js on the Linux server?

Comment: I don't think there would be a problem. But if I wanted to do the same I would use the shell script. I'd rather have fewer services running on the server all the time.

Comment: I guess serverless is a perfect candidate for this. Something like using cloudwatch events for cron expression which will trigger lambda function in place of script or js file which will do all the mongo stuff. Obviously this using AWS.

Comment: @BamdadNouri What about js file instead of sh file?